# Skip login screen while opening a vue route link

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using laravel and vue js in my app. All the vue routes ask for a login when opened as i am using laravel auth. I want to create some routes that should be accessable without a user to be logged in. In other words I want some route that can be accessed by guest user as well. But at the moment all routes require user to be authenticated. These are my routes

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard_admin', component:  require('./components/dashboard.vue').default},
    { path: '/ongoing_events_admin', component:  require('./components/events.vue').default } ,
    { path: '/courses_admin', component:  require('./components/courses.vue').default},
    { path: '/front_images_admin', component:  require('./components/front_images.vue').default},
    { path: '/news_admin', component:  require('./components/news.vue').default},


    { path: '/main', component:  require('./components/main_view/index_view_general.vue') ,
    name: 'index',
    props: true ,
    beforeEnter:DontrequireLogin
    },


    //general vue

  // { path: '/', component:  require('./components/main_view/index_view_general.vue').default},

  ]


  const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
  })



const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});
```

These are my routes. I want some of these routes that can be accessed by guest user as well but at the moment all routes require user to be logged in.

Comment: Do you have any navigation guard set up? Can you post it here?

Comment: No I haven't set up any navigation gaurd manually. The login form is automatically shown when i open a vue route.

Comment: I think @YomS. is saying that you need to check your server route.  Your Vue does not have a /login route.  This mean your Login page is using the default Laravel cookie Auth and you have a Server-Side Guard somewhere on the Laravel Web route.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do this meta's, for more about this you can read from its official documentation [Route Meta](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html)

Let me explain litle bit what meta's do .

in meta you define a bolean object which indicate , this route is for authenticated or users or for guest user. let see below example.

i have authenticated route, only for authenticated users.

```
{path: '/account-setting',component:accountSetting,meta:{auth:true}},
```

so i pass auth object in meta and decide in route.beforeach what to do with this route.

so same a normal route

```
{path: '/about',component:about}
```

in this i give no meta, which means its for all user.

read the documentation to know how to use it.

Comment: I have also set no meta but still the vue is requiring user to login ...

Comment: { path: '/main', component:  require('./components/main_view/index_view_general.vue') ,
    name: 'index',
    props: true ,
    },

Comment: you need to add some middlewear. see route.beforeEach in documentation for understanding how its works